# Syntax problem with html in PHP

Tags: php, html, syntax, tags

im getting a syntax error on this line of code and don't know the correct formatting for it.

This is the part i'm having problems with -

```
echo " 
   <ul>";  

foreach($photos as $photo) {  

           $farm              = $photo['farm'];  
           $server            = $photo['server'];  
           $photo_id          = $photo['id'];  
           $secret            = $photo['secret'];  
           $photo_title       = $photo['title'];  

<li><img src="http://farm'.$photo['farm'].'.static.flickr.com/'.$photo['server'].'/'.$photo['id'].'_'.$photo['secret'].'_t.jpg" alt="'.$photo['title'].'" ></li>
```

The problem is with that li tag. How can i format it properly?

Comment: have you forgotten to place the echo in last line?

Comment: You also need to close your foreach loop

Comment: and to close the foreach brace. Unless your loop is longer than you have copy/pasted

Comment: What's the point of assigning variables if you aren't going to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, you probably mean to have the following for your last line:

```
echo '<li><img src="http://farm'.$photo['farm'].'.static.flickr.com/'.$photo['server'].'/'.$photo['id'].'_'.$photo['secret'].'_t.jpg" alt="'.$photo['title'].'" ></li>';
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to close the foreach loop `}` (this might be in OP's code, but omitted for brevity sake)

Comment: @William, I didn't want to make any assumptions as the OP only mentioned the line in question.

Comment: Thanks for that guys. cheers William for pointing out i needed to close my loop :)

Answer (score 2):

The `<li>` part should be quoted. Try:

```
echo " 
   <ul>";  

foreach($photos as $photo) {  

           $farm              = $photo['farm'];  
           $server            = $photo['server'];  
           $photo_id          = $photo['id'];  
           $secret            = $photo['secret'];  
           $photo_title       = $photo['title'];  

    echo '<li><img src="http://farm' . $photo['farm'] . 'static.flickr.com/' . $photo['server'] . '/' . $photo['id'] . '_' . $photo['secret'] . '_t.jpg" alt="' . $photo['title'] . '" ></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```